# How to get set in composition api for step form?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to create a multi step form with composition api.
In vue 2 I used to do it this way

```
    email: {
                get() {
                    return this.$store.state.email
                },
                set(value) {
                    this.$store.commit("setEmail", value)
                }
            },
```

Now I have my own store, I made this computed property to pass to my component `stEmail: computed(() => state.email)`. How can I actually use this in get set?

I am trying do something like this but completely doesn't work.

```
  let setMail = computed(({
    get() {
      return stEmail;
    },
    set(val) {
      stEmail.value = val;
    }
  }))
```

```js
const state = reactive({
  email: "",
})


export function useGlobal() {

  return {
    ...toRefs(state),
    number,
  }
}
```

Or is there better way now to make multi step forms?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do the same with the Composition API. Import `useStore` from the `vuex` package and `computed` from `vue`:

```
import { computed } from 'vue';
import { useStore } from 'vuex';
```

And then use it in your `setup()` function like this:

```
setup: () => {
  const store = useStore();

  const email = computed({
    get() {
      return store.state.email;
    },
    set(value) {
      store.commit("setEmail", value);
    }
  });

  return { email };
}
```

---

If you want to avoid using `vuex`, you can just define variables with `ref()` and export them in a regular JavaScript file. This would make your state reusable in multiple files.

state.js

```
export const email = ref('initial@value');
```

Form1.vue/Form2.vue

```
<template>
  <input v-model="email" />
</template>

<script>
import { email } from './state';

export default {
  setup() {
    return { email };
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: What is `useGlobal` and why are you building your own solution when there is `vuex`?

Comment: Because I dont use vue 2, and everyone says vuex is terrible for composition api, because comp api allows to build own composables.

Comment: I've added an example with a shared local state, without using `vuex`.

Comment: And that's it? only v-model is required for this? Will the state not dissapear when I move onto next page?

Comment: Using `computed(() => ({` with the anonymous function didn't work for me, I had to omit the anonymous function for it to work 
`const email = computed({ get() { return store.state.email; }, set(value) { store.commit("setEmail", value); } });`

Comment: @Gregor You are right, that was a typo, which is now fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As Gregor pointed out, the accepted answer included an anonymous function that doesn't seem to work, but it will work if you just get rid of that part. Here's an example using `<script setup>` SFC

```js
<script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue'
import { useStore } from 'vuex'
const store = useStore()

const email = computed({
    get() {
      return store.state.email
    },
    set(value) {
      store.commit("setEmail", value)
    }
})
</script>

<template>
    <input type="email" v-model="email" />
</template>
```